# Databricks unit testing with Nutter

Tags: unit-testing, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I m trying to run unit test inside Databricks with Nutter but return always `None`

notebook1

```
def add_nums(a, b):
    return a + b
```

notebook2 (Where I want to make the unit test)

```
%pip install nutter 
from runtime.nutterfixture import NutterFixture, tag
```

import the notebook1 in notebook 2

```
%run /notebook1/
```

I just make a tes to verify function in notebook1 is correctly added.

```
print(add_nums(1, 3)) # return 4 so everything fine.

class gcTestClass(NutterFixture):
    def test_add(self):
        assert (add_nums(1, 3) == 4)

result = gcTestClass().execute_tests()
print(result.to_string())
```

I get that output

Notebook: N/A - Lifecycle State: N/A, Result: N/A
Run Page URL: N/A

==================================================

No test cases were returned.
Notebook output: None

could somebody help me to figure out what I m doig wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: you can find more examples here: https://github.com/alexott/databricks-nutter-repos-demo. Also, if you use Databricks Repos, then you can define code in the Python files that could be used as Python modules, with all things like, module scope, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include "asssertion_" at the beginning of the assertion test function:

```
class gcTestClass(NutterFixture):
    def assertion_test_add(self):
        assert (add_nums(1, 3) == 4)

# COMMAND ----------

result = gcTestClass().execute_tests()
print(result.to_string())
```